# Ecto query - order_by field in jsonb column

Tags: elixir, ecto

The following code works fine when ordering an Ecto query by the **created_at** column.

```js
sort_params = [asc: :created_at]
query = from user in users,
      order_by: ^sort_params,
      limit: ^page_size,
      offset: ^offset
```

Assuming I have a database column of type **jsonb** called info, and one of the fields in the JSON object is "status", is there a way to sort by that field?
Does Ecto have a valid equivalent to something like

`sort_params = [asc: :info.status]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

You can use [Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1) for that.

```
# you can use fragment/1 only directly in the query

query = from user in users,
  order_by: fragment("info->>'status' ASC"),
  limit: ^page_size,
  offset: ^offset
```